# Jenkins file can we use the IF statement

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

in Jenkins file one of the variable is having the comma separated values like below.

> infra_services=[abc,def,xyz]

when I write the below code it was throwing an error.

```
if ("{$Infra_Services}".contains("xyz"))
    then
 echo "$Infra_Services"
fi
```

Comment: can you please share the error message  ?

Comment: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: str for class: WorkflowScript
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:458)
 at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.getProperty(DefaultInvoker.java:39)
 at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
 at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:23)

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do if statements in a Jenkinsfile. However if you are using declarative pipeline you need to brace it with the step `script`.

Your issue comes from the fact you did not put any double quotes around "abc" and all the elements of your array

```
infra_services=[abc,def,xyz]
```

​
A second error will raise after you fix this. If `infra_services` is an array, to manipulate it you should not try to cast it as string. It should throw when you do "{$Infra_Services}"

here is a working example

```
​def Infra_Services = ["abc","def","xyz"]

if (Infra_Services.contains("xyz")) {
   println "found"
}​​
```

My advice is to test your groovy before running it on jenkins, you will gain precious time. Here is a good online groovy console I use to test my code. running the groovy console from terminal is an alternative

https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Actually I am trying to read the JIRA issue values in Jenkins job.
One is checkbox field contains a 5 values with comma separated.
In that field values I have split in a separate values and search using the If statement

Comment: this is another question. I would try something like `def output = "hello ABC-103";

def (isJiraIssue) = output =~ /(?<!([A-Za-z]{1,10})-?)[A-Z]+-\d+/;

println isJiraIssue [0]​`